# MessageProcessor looses values when processing -> InvalidInputException: Duplicate key, Movie Id: 333, Review Id:0

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, microservices

I am working with simple set of microservices and two strange things happen during message processing and saving values.

```
review_1           | 2020-01-29 16:55:52.867 ERROR 1 --- [.reviewsGroup-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking com.geborskimateusz.microservices.core.review.service.MessageProcessor#process[1 args]; nested exception is com.geborskimateusz.util.exceptions.InvalidInputException: Duplicate key, Movie Id: 333, Review Id:0, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[197], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=reviews, amqp_deliveryTag=3, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=reviews.reviewsGroup, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=reviews, amqp_timestamp=Wed Jan 29 16:55:49 GMT 2020, amqp_messageId=95b4bae5-b5ab-12a1-462a-567252c04778, id=b88df7f0-b6ad-b26b-5280-a80a4396efd7, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-NcAue9uq8t8rQC_EmY9cZQ, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1580316951325}]
review_1           |    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:63)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:451)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:400)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1100(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:58)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:211)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:208)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1400)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1387)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1366)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:848)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:832)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1073)
review_1           |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
review_1           | Caused by: com.geborskimateusz.util.exceptions.InvalidInputException: Duplicate key, Movie Id: 333, Review Id:0
review_1           |    at com.geborskimateusz.microservices.core.review.service.BaseReviewService.createReview(BaseReviewService.java:58)
review_1           |    at com.geborskimateusz.microservices.core.review.service.MessageProcessor.process(MessageProcessor.java:34)
review_1           |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
review_1           |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
review_1           |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
review_1           |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
review_1           |    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
review_1           |    ... 27 more
```

First, when when I am preparing Object to send througth message reviewId equals some value, for example 437 where when message is received in Message processor this, and only this value is lost somehow and it is just 0, i will represent its with code and logs:

Method which will send message is like:

```
 @Override
    public Review createReview(Review review) {
        log.info("MovieCompositeIntegration.createReview(Review review), passed argument: {}", review.toString());

        messageSources.outputReviews()
                .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(
                        new Event<>(Event.Type.CREATE, review.getMovieId(), review)
                ).build());

        return review;
    }
```

You can see review.toString which in logs has value of reviewId:
The log from composite service:

```
movie-composite_1  | 2020-01-29 16:01:32.327  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] c.g.m.c.m.s.MovieCompositeIntegration    : MovieCompositeIntegration.createReview(Review review), passed argument: Review{movieId=333, reviewId=451, author='author 1', subject='subject 1', content='content 1', serviceAddress='null'}
```

This method sends message to review microservice where CREATE event looks like:

```
@Slf4j
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class MessageProcessor {

    private final ReviewService reviewService;

    public MessageProcessor(ReviewService reviewService) {
        this.reviewService = reviewService;
    }

    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
    public void process(Event<Integer, Review> event) {

        log.info("Process message created at {}...", event.getEventCreatedAt());
        log.info("Process message body: {}", event.toString());

        switch (event.getEventType()) {

            case CREATE:
                Review review = event.getData();
                log.info("Create review with ID: {}/{}", review.getMovieId(), review.getReviewId());
                log.info(review.toString());
                reviewService.createReview(review);
                break;

            default:
                String errorMessage = "Incorrect event type: " + event.getEventType() + ", expected a CREATE or DELETE event";
                log.warn(errorMessage);
                throw new EventProcessingException(errorMessage);
        }

        log.info("Message processing done!");
    }
}
```

and here this and only this value of reviewId is missing, logs are like:

```
    review_1           | 2020-01-29 16:01:32.433  INFO 1 --- [.reviewsGroup-1] c.g.m.c.review.service.MessageProcessor  : Process message created at 2020-01-29T16:01:32.319482...
    review_1           | 2020-01-29 16:01:32.433  INFO 1 --- [.reviewsGroup-1] c.g.m.c.review.service.MessageProcessor  : Process message body: Event{eventType=CREATE, key=333, data=Review{movieId=333, reviewId=0, author='author 1', subject='null', content='content 1', serviceAddress='null'}, eventCreatedAt=2020-01-29T16:01:32.319482}
    review_1           | 2020-01-29 16:01:32.434  INFO 1 --- [.reviewsGroup-1] c.g.m.c.review.service.MessageProcessor  : Create review with ID: 333/0
    review_1           | 2020-01-29 16:01:32.434  INFO 1 --- [.reviewsGroup-1] c.g.m.c.review.service.MessageProcessor  : Review{movieId=333, reviewId=0, author='author 1', subject='null', content='content 1', serviceAddress='null'}
```

Because of this (probably) when saving to database this error is thrown:

```
review_1           | 2020-01-29 16:01:34.151 ERROR 1 --- [.reviewsGroup-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking com.geborskimateusz.microservices.core.review.service.MessageProcessor#process[1 args]; nested exception is com.geborskimateusz.util.exceptions.InvalidInputException: Duplicate key, Movie Id: 333, Review Id:0, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[197], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=reviews, amqp_deliveryTag=2, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=reviews.reviewsGroup, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=reviews, amqp_timestamp=Wed Jan 29 16:01:32 GMT 2020, amqp_messageId=b9f05c16-67a5-a823-de74-5f519f14d8b3, id=4ddedcea-3938-0e03-0ac8-536e5149f50b, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-GaxrablC0mlEtccmO7yVLw, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1580313692567}]
```

What is more, even if reviewId is somehow changed from concrete value to 0 default behavior should recognize this Entity as new one  but exception is thrown. What I am missing here? I am struggling with this for about a week, I am out of ideas, any help will be appreciated. 
I am attaching also additional code of Event and Review:

Review:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Review {
    private final int movieId;
    private final int reviewId;
    private final String author;
    private final String subject;
    private final String content;
    private String serviceAddress;

    public Review() {
        movieId = 0;
        reviewId = 0;
        author = null;
        subject = null;
        content = null;
        serviceAddress = null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Review{" +
                "movieId=" + movieId +
                ", reviewId=" + reviewId +
                ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", subject='" + subject + '\'' +
                ", content='" + content + '\'' +
                ", serviceAddress='" + serviceAddress + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

ReviewEntity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "reviews", indexes = { @Index(name = "reviews_unique_idx", unique = true, columnList = "movieId,reviewId") })
public class ReviewEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private Integer movieId;
    private Integer reviewId;
    private String author;
    private String subject;
    private String content;
    private String serviceAddress;

    public ReviewEntity(Integer movieId, Integer reviewId, String author, String subject, String content, String serviceAddress) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.reviewId = reviewId;
        this.author = author;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
        this.serviceAddress = serviceAddress;
    }
}
```

and Event:

```
@Getter
public class Event<K, T> {

    public enum Type {CREATE, DELETE}

    private Event.Type eventType;
    private K key;
    private T data;
    private LocalDateTime eventCreatedAt;

    public Event() {
        this.eventType = null;
        this.key = null;
        this.data = null;
        this.eventCreatedAt = null;
    }

    public Event(Type eventType, K key, T data) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.key = key;
        this.data = data;
        this.eventCreatedAt = now();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Event{" +
                "eventType=" + eventType +
                ", key=" + key +
                ", data=" + data +
                ", eventCreatedAt=" + eventCreatedAt +
                '}';
    }
}
```